# How to identify the hard drive partition with the OS installed using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ubuntu server, with 2 hard disks /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. The OS is installed under /dev/sdb. I need to write an ansible playbook with a task. This task should pass only for the following conditions:

1. if the drive has no partition like /dev/sda and also has no OS installed (is this possible? I believe if there is OS installed, then there will be partitions on the hard disks?)
2. if the drive has partitions like /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 etc but no OS installed in any of those partitions.

After searching, I wrote this playbook:

```
  - name: check OS install
    fail:
      msg: "partition has OS installed"
    when:
    - item.key is search('sd*')
    - item.value.partitions is mapping
    - item.value.partitions | length != 0 or item.value.partitions is search('ubuntu*')
    loop: "{{ ansible_devices | dict2items }}"
```

But not sure whether I am doing the right thing here because this is failing for /dev/sdb but does not loop over /dev/sda since it has no partitions

Comment: 1) You will have to be much more specific as what you consider being a sign of "a partition contains your OS": are you looking for the boot partition, the root partition, an EFI partition, a partition which is part of a lvm volume group with possilbly other partitions/disks and where a logical volume has been created containing your root/boot filesystem....? 2) This question does not belong to SO (not a programming question) and should go to https://superuser.com

Comment: @Zeitounator, I wrote this playbook based on your answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  - name: check OS drive
    debug:
      msg: "OS installed"
    when:
      - item.key is search('sd*')
      - item.value.partitions is not search(ansible_facts.distribution | lower)
    loop: "{{ ansible_devices | dict2items }}"
```